# dotnet publish include extra files

Tags: .net, .net-core, .net-core-2.0

I have a netcore application depends on my custom project. Because I cannot reference it directly, I have written postbuildevents that are copying my files to output:

```
xcopy "$(SolutionDir)Ethereum.Contracts\bin\$(ConfigurationName)\*.abi" "$(TargetDir)" /Y /I
xcopy "$(SolutionDir)Ethereum.Contracts\bin\$(ConfigurationName)\*.bin" "$(TargetDir)" /Y /I
```

It works fine when I build and run project, but when run `publish` command it doesn't include these files.

How can it be done? I tried [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45998779/dotnet-publish-doesnt-include-files-generated-during-post-build-event) as well but `AddPayloadsFolder` doesn't get called.

My `csproj`:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\..\Dependencies\Dependencies.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="appsettings.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="log4net.config">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>

  <Target Name="PostBuild" AfterTargets="PostBuildEvent">
    <Exec Command="xcopy &quot;$(SolutionDir)Ethereum.Contracts\bin\$(ConfigurationName)\*.abi&quot; &quot;$(TargetDir)&quot; /Y /I&#xA;&#xA;&#xD;&#xA;xcopy &quot;$(SolutionDir)Ethereum.Contracts\bin\$(ConfigurationName)\*.bin&quot; &quot;$(TargetDir)&quot; /Y /I" />
  </Target>

  <Target Name="AddPayloadsFolder" AfterTargets="AfterPublish">
    <Exec Command="xcopy &quot;$(TargetDir)\*.abi&quot; &quot;$(PublishDir)&quot; /Y /I&#xA;&#xA;&#xD;&#xA;xcopy &quot;$(TargetDir)\*.bin&quot; &quot;$(PublishDir)&quot; /Y /I" />
  </Target>

</Project>
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When you launch `dotnet publish` command, `$(SolutionDir)` macros is not defined. As result `xcopy` is launched with incorrect source path.

The issue with missing solution macros is [described here](https://github.com/dotnet/project-system/issues/2983) and it's still in opened state. I'm not sure it will be ever fixed because `$(SolutionDir)` is IDE-specific macros.

To fix your problem, you could pass the value for `$(SolutionDir)` macros to `dotnet publish` command via switch `/p`:

> dotnet publish -c Release -r win-x64
>   /p:SolutionDir="D:\projects\SolutionDir"

You should also add a backslash after `$(SolutionDir)` macros:

```
<Target Name="PostBuild" AfterTargets="PostBuildEvent">
    <Exec Command="xcopy &quot;$(SolutionDir)\Ethereum.Contracts\bin\$(ConfigurationName)\*.abi&quot; &quot;$(TargetDir)&quot; /Y /I&#xA;&#xA;&#xD;&#xA;xcopy &quot;$(SolutionDir)\Ethereum.Contracts\bin\$(ConfigurationName)\*.bin&quot; &quot;$(TargetDir)&quot; /Y /I" />
</Target>
```

**UPDATE** (regarding `AddPayloadsFolder` target):

`AddPayloadsFolder` target defined as

```
<Target Name="AddPayloadsFolder" AfterTargets="AfterPublish">
```

is not executed since the correct value of `AfterTargets` for `dotnet publish` is `Publish`, not `AfterPublish`. I have not found explicit documentation for this fact, however it is mentioned in [this issue](https://github.com/aspnet/websdk/issues/152#issuecomment-348560793).

Also consider replacing several `xcopy` commands delimited by newline separator with multiple commands. When I got `AddPayloadsFolder` target finally executed, I got an error caused by `\r` delimiter appended to the command line.

Summarizing all of the above, here are adjusted `PostBuild` and `AddPayloadsFolder` targets:

```
<Target Name="PostBuild" AfterTargets="PostBuildEvent">
    <Exec Command="xcopy &quot;$(SolutionDir)\Ethereum.Contracts\bin\$(ConfigurationName)\*.abi&quot; &quot;$(TargetDir)&quot; /Y /I" />
    <Exec Command="xcopy &quot;$(SolutionDir)\Ethereum.Contracts\bin\$(ConfigurationName)\*.bin&quot; &quot;$(TargetDir)&quot; /Y /I" />
</Target>

<Target Name="AddPayloadsFolder" AfterTargets="Publish">
    <Exec Command="xcopy &quot;$(TargetDir)*.abi&quot; &quot;$(PublishDir)&quot; /Y /I" />
    <Exec Command="xcopy &quot;$(TargetDir)*.bin&quot; &quot;$(PublishDir)&quot; /Y /I" />
</Target>
```

Comment: Well, I get this file copied into `bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.0` folder (as it was with Visual Studio publish option). However, `\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.0\publish` still not containing these files. This was purpose of `AddPayloadsFolder` task. You can try yourself add any text file which is not part of project. E.g. try to copy `csproj` file itself in output directory. You can easily copy it into `bin/debug` folder but it doesn't go into `publish` one.

Comment: Thank you, it works as expected. I didn't separate it into more readable `Exec`'s because it's how it's generated in Visual Studio, otherwise only first command gets shown in VS project properties.

Comment: Thx, works. But I prefer it like this: https://gist.github.com/jakubsuchybio/7efe6aa1147f088072459a39837f2ecd

Answer (score 4):

Based no the [gist](https://gist.github.com/jakubsuchybio/7efe6aa1147f088072459a39837f2ecd) that [@Jacob](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5440166/jacob) suggested, I have written down the recommended method to do this in SDK-style csproj files.

You first need to setup an item group that specifies the files that you want to copy. Then you can use a target to perform the actual copy step. This is an example taken from the VS website ([link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/copy-task?view=vs-2019)):

```xml
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
 <ItemGroup>
  <MySourceFiles Include="a.cs;b.cs;c.cs"/>
 </ItemGroup>
 <Target Name="CopyFiles">
  <Copy SourceFiles="@(MySourceFiles)" DestinationFolder="c:\MyProject\Destination" />
 </Target>
</Project>
```

You also need to specify when the target needs to be invoked (unless you want to invoke it explicitly). For a normal build you would typically invoked it after the build (`AfterBuild`). When publishing the project, select the `Publish` target. If it needs to be done both times, then invoke it twice:

```xml
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
 <ItemGroup>
  <MySourceFiles Include="a.cs;b.cs;c.cs"/>
 </ItemGroup>
 <Target Name="CopyExtraFiles" AfterTargets="AfterBuild">
  <Copy SourceFiles="@(MySourceFiles)" DestinationFolder="c:\MyProject\Destination" />
 </Target>
 <Target Name="PublishExtraFiles" AfterTargets="Publish">
  <Copy SourceFiles="@(MySourceFiles)" DestinationFolder="c:\MyProject\Destination" />
 </Target>
</Project>
```

See for more information the documentation about the [Copy task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/copy-task). You may need this when you want to copy a folder when you need to copy a complete directory structure:

```
<Copy SourceFiles="@(MySourceFiles)"
      DestinationFiles="@(MySourceFiles->'c:\MyDestinationTree\%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)')" />
```

Answer (score 1):

A comment on SolutionDir being unavailable - not as an answer to the question per se but as something to consider.

If you create a file in your solution directory called "Directory.Build.props", with the following content, then it defines the SolutionDir variable for you:

```
<Project>
 <PropertyGroup>
    <SolutionDir>$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)</SolutionDir>
 </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```